# How to set font size "e" in ConTeXt?

Tags: fontsize, context, context-mkiv

According to the ConTeXt manuals, there is a font size "e", the largest available font size. Whenever I try to use this, however, the command fails. What is the proper way to enable this font size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  support for an "e" size has been discontinued in the core. But if you want it, it is easy to add, like so (somewhere before your `\setupbodyfont`):

```
\definefontsize[e]
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][e=2.5]
```